# How can I create a permission using an alter hook?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In particular, I am trying to prevent users from reaching admin/config without certain rights. I'm guessing my code will look something like this:

```
    function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['admin/config']['????'] = ?????;
}
```

Am I on the right track here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the good way. You can create a permission with a hook_permission (just return an array) and override your menu entry with your new permission.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['admin/config']['access arguments'] = array('your_new_permission');
}
```

If you don't want create a custom permission you can use "access callback" of hook_menu api.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks so much! Right now I have 'function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['admin/config']['access arguments'] = array('Administer users');
}'. Shouldn't this mean that only users with the "administer users" permission can view admin/config? IT doesn't seem to be working that way...

Comment: Have you create "Administer users" with a hook_permission ? If yes please rename it because this permission already exist for another module. After if you use your drupal administrator (first user created during installation with uid = 1) you will not see any change because this user is Super Admin and  have **all** permissions. For your test create a new admin user.